# VBA Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' failed

Tags: excel, vba

i try to save split my excel file when I use my macro file with another pc and run macro code will fail with

"Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' failed

VBA code

```
Option Explicit

Const Target_Folder As String = "C:\OutputData\"
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsHelper As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long

    Private Sub SplitWorksheet(ByVal Category_Name As Variant)
    Dim dif As Variant
    dif = "_DeviceInfo"
    
    Dim n As String
    n = String(5 - Len(Category_Name), "0") & Category_Name
    
    
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Add
    With wsSource
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
            .AutoFilter .Range("M1").Column, Category_Name
       .Copy

            'wbTarget.Worksheets(1).Paste
           
           wbTarget.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        True, Transpose:=True
           
            wbTarget.Worksheets(1).Name = Category_Name & dif
            wbTarget.SaveAs Target_Folder & n & dif & ".csv", 62
            wbTarget.Close False
            
        End With
        
    End With
    
    Set wbTarget = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

please help me this run time error 1004

Comment: What does `Target_Folder & n & dif & ".csv"` evaluate to?

Comment: `wbTarget.SaveAs Target_Folder & n & dif & ".csv", 62` The fileformat for CSV is `xlCSV` which has a value of `6` and not `62`

Comment: @SiddharthRout `62` is UTF-8 CSV. shouldn't be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the file format from `62` to `6` and it works now.

```
wbTarget.SaveAs Target_Folder & n & dif & ".csv", 6
```